# How to add assertions to Galting test using Karate?

Tags: performance-testing, karate, web-api-testing

We have an API which will return 200 or 400 based on slots available,
We need to write a test, which triggers 20 requests for 10 slots 
Need to assert 10 success 10 failure for the same test,
No sure, This scenario is a right use case to use karate gatling,
As our entire project was using the karate for our functional testing,

**Problem Statement**
We have api which will register users for sessions based on the slots available (you can consider these tickets for the movie).
We have implemented in such a way if there are 10 slots, 20 requests come in => 10 will get success, 10 will get failure.
We wrote a karate test for the above scenario and used Gatling with twenty users,
On looking into the Gatling reports, All works perfectly.
10 Success, 10 failure in the report.

Challenge comes when the Gatling build will not fail for the above scenario, it will generate a report.
I tried to use Gatling assertions as part of the simulation file, but the assertion object is empty.

```
 "assertions": []
```

Sample test

```
Scenario: Register slot for multiple users to test concurrent booking
    * def bearerAuthorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    * def slotId = 1
    * print slotId
    Given path 'movie/slots/' + slotId + '/registrations'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    When request {}
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

Simulation script

```
val sessionApi = scenario("sessions-api")
    .feed(users)
    .exec(karateFeature("classpath:featureTests/register-sessions-concurrent.feature"))

setUp(
    sessionApi.inject(rampUsers(10) during (2 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
)
```

Note:
I have tried below approaches,
1. tried to create a variable as successCount at feature level and tried to update the depending upon the
status of the req, the global variable gets overridden on each gatling execution and not sure on how to use it for
making the build failure
2. Tried using the gatling assertions, for specific using details("Index") but need to know the "group" of the feature test.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a variable as `successCount` at feature level"? 
In Karate only scenarios are executed. Every Scenario gets a new context. You cannot write a variable in one scenario and read/update it in an other.

Comment: please refer answers and discussion for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59354367/143475 - this is an area where I think most teams don't put in complicated assertions like you want to do - so you may need to figure some of this out on your own. please post back any solutions you find just like the other OP - pay it forward, and help others please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I have is you can design a Java singleton - and update it in your feature files. You just need to take care of concurrency, and a simple way would be to use an `AtomicInteger` or something like that.

You can easily get a reference to this singleton from the Scala / Gatling test. And then you should be able to figure out a way in Gatling to manually fail the test.